# How to place object files into a different directory using Makefile?

Tags: makefile, compilation

Consider the following Makefile fragment:

```
FORTRAN = ifort -c
PATH_MOD = mod/
FILE_MOD = mod_constant.f90 mod_rot.f mod_test.f90
SOURCE_MOD = $(FILE_MOD:%=$(PATH_MOD)%)
OBJECT_MOD = $(FILE_MOD:%.f*=%.o)

$(OBJECT_MOD): $(SOURCE_MOD)
   $(FORTRAN) $(SOURCE_MOD)

clean:
   rm -f *.o
```

This script executes the command `ifort -c mod_constant.f90 mod_rot.f mod_test.f90`.

However, I would like to achieve that all files listed in `$(FILE_MOD)` [but none of the other files in directory `$(PATH_MOD)$`] will be compiled **in separate lines**, placing the object files into directory `lnk`.
In the present case, the script should run the following sequence of commands:

```
ifort -c mod_constant.f90 -o lnk/mod_constant.o
ifort -c mod_rot.f -o lnk/mod_rot.o
ifort -c mod_test.f90 -o lnk/mod_test.o
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand the title of your question.  What do you  mean by _in a simultaneous way_?

Comment: @MadScientist Actually, it is not relevant. I have removed that phrase.

Comment: John gives you a good answer.  But I'm sure that if you typed the (new) title of this question into Google or your favorite search engine, you would have found lots of examples and answers, including on StackOverflow.  This is a VERY common question.

Comment: @MadScientist John gave me a partial answer, supposing that there are no conflicts with other files (e.g., other object files in lnk, other .f90 and .f files). I have made an intensive search, but haven't found a solution which can use the `$(SOURCE_MOD)` variable to specify which files need to be compiled.

Comment: I don't understand what you want.  Make will only build the object files you asked it to build.  In your example above, you construct the `OBJECT_MOD` variable contents from the `SOURCE_MOD` contents, and so those object files are the only ones which will be compiled.  This matches the output you show above as "should run the following sequence of commands".

Comment: @MadScientist Put it another way: from where the Makefile knows that `lnk/%.o : %.f`[newline] `$(FORTRAN) -c $< -o $@`  should use only `mod_rot.f`, and none of the other .f files in the same directory?

Comment: You should just try it and see.  Pattern rules are just templates, that make uses to figure out how to build the targets you ask it to build.  They are not equivalent to glob statements like `ls *.f` which will go out to the disk and find all files that could be built.  That's not how make works.

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks for your detailed comments. In fact, I had some other problems in my Makefile which I managed to convert into an MWE (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77441283/what-causes-a-conflict-between-pattern-rules-in-the-makefile-below). Your suggestions are really appreciated under that question, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule ...

> ```
> $(OBJECT_MOD): $(SOURCE_MOD)
>     $(FORTRAN) $(SOURCE_MOD)
> ```

Says that *each* target in the list to which `$(OBJECT_MOD)` expands has as prerequisites *all* the files in the list to which `$(SOURCE_MOD)` expands, and should be built by the command to which `$(FORTRAN) $(SOURCE_MOD)` expands.  That's not at all what you want.

> I would like to achieve that all files listed in `$(FILE_MOD)` [but none of the other files in directory `$(PATH_MOD)$`] will be compiled **in separate lines**, placing the object files into directory `lnk`.

Since you seem already commited to GNU's version of `make`, the natural way to go about this is to write a pattern rule.  Or two, actually, because you have two distinct source name patterns.  If you want the object files to go into a different directory than their corresponding sources, then that would also be handled in such rules.  For example,

```
lnk/%.o : %.f
        $(FORTRAN) -c $< -o $@

lnk/%.o : %.f90
        $(FORTRAN) -c $< -o $@
```

The `%` can be interpreted as a wildcard, with the caveat that the appearance in the rule's target and those in its prerequisite list have to expand to the same string.

The `$<` is an automatic variable that expands to the first actual element of the rule's prerequisite list, subject to expansion of the `%`.  The `$@` expands to the actual target being built.

Also, note well that those rules tell *how* to build the wanted files, but you still need somehow to tell `make` that they need to be built at all.  That would typically be by making them prerequisites of some rule, though you could rely instead on requesting one or more of them explicitly, from the `make` command line.

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer. However, I would like to treat all these three *.f(90) files with the same rule, excluding other .f(90) files. I tried `lnk/%.o : %.f*` [newline] `$(FORTRAN) -c $< -o $@`, but it cannot treat if there are other *.f(90) and .o files in the source/target directory. The `$(OBJECT_MOD)/$(SOURCE_MOD)` variable would tell which files to compile, but I don't know how to use these variables in your Makefile rule. Do you have a solution to this problem?

Comment: @JohnBollinger was maybe not completely clear: you should _remove_ the existing rule you have for `$(OBJECT_MOD): $(SOURCE_MOD)` (including the recipe) and _replace_ it with the pattern rules he shows here.  Then you should _also_ add a target that depends on the files you want to be built; for example: `all: $(OBJECT_MOD)`

Comment: @RolandTóbiás, you do not have to rely on the pattern rules presented here to build any other files, with the caveat being that you can have only one pattern rule for each distinct combination of target pattern and prerequisites pattern.  Pattern rules would definitely require you to have a different (pattern) rule for `.f` sources than you do for `.f90` sources, however.  That's a limitation of `make`.

Comment: @RolandTóbiás, as this answer already says, you would engage these rules by telling `make` that targets matched (only) by these rules need to be built.  MadScientist spoke to that, but I should add that none of the variables presently defined in the code in your question provide for this.  You probably want `OBJECT_MOD` to serve in this role, but it is presently naming object files in the source directory, whereas you want it to name object files in the destination directory (`lnk/`).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks for your detailed explanations. In fact, I had some other problems in my Makefile which I managed to convert into an MWE (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77441283/what-causes-a-conflict-between-pattern-rules-in-the-makefile-below). Your suggestions are really appreciated under that question, as well.