# What causes a conflict between pattern rules in the Makefile below?

Tags: makefile, compilation, gnu-make

Consider the following Makefile as an MWE:

```
###################################################################
# first bunch
###################################################################
FORTRAN1 = ifort -c
PATH1 = sub/
FILE1 = first.f90
SOURCE1 = $(FILE_TEST:%=$(PATH1)%)
OBJECT1 = $(addprefix lnk/,$(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(FILE1))))
###################################################################
#second bunch
###################################################################
FORTRAN2 = ifort -traceback -c
PATH2 = sub/
FILE2 = second.f90
SOURCE2 = $(FILE2:%=$(PATH2)%)
OBJECT2 = $(addprefix lnk/,$(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(FILE2))))
###################################################################
# first rule
###################################################################
all: $(OBJECT1)
lnk/%.o: $(PATH1)%.f90
   $(FORTRAN1) -o $@ $<
###################################################################
# second rule
###################################################################
all: $(OBJECT2)
lnk/%.o: $(PATH2)%.f90
   $(FORTRAN2) -o $@ $<
```

When I run this script, the following commands are executed:

```
ifort -traceback -c -o lnk/first.o sub/first.f90
ifort -traceback -c -o lnk/second.o sub/second.f90
```

In other words, both the first and second rules use `FORTRAN2=ifort -traceback -c`, while the first rule should use `FORTRAN1=ifort -c`. Could you please help me what is responsible for this strange behavior? How can I achieve that `$(FORTRAN1)$` should be used by the first rule?

**EDIT #1:**

Following MadScientist's suggestion, I tried the following:

```
###################################################################
# first bunch
###################################################################
FORTRAN1 = ifort -c
PATH1 = sub/
FILE1 = first.f90
SOURCE1 = $(FILE_TEST:%=$(PATH1)%)
OBJECT1 = $(addprefix lnk/,$(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(FILE1))))
###################################################################
#second bunch
###################################################################
FORTRAN2 = ifort -traceback -c
PATH2 = sub/
FILE2 = second.f90
SOURCE2 = $(FILE2:%=$(PATH2)%)
OBJECT2 = $(addprefix lnk/,$(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(FILE2))))
###################################################################
# first rule
###################################################################
$(OBJECT1): lnk/%.o: $(PATH1)%.f90
   $(FORTRAN1) -o $@ $<
###################################################################
# second rule
###################################################################
$(OBJECT2): lnk/%.o: $(PATH2)%.f90
   $(FORTRAN2) -o $@ $<
```

However, it executes only one (that is, the first) command:

```
ifort -c -o lnk/first.o sub/first.f90
```

**EDIT #2:**

The problem was that I removed the `all:` targets. The correct file content should be:

```
###################################################################
# first bunch
###################################################################
FORTRAN1 = ifort -c
PATH1 = sub/
FILE1 = first.f90
SOURCE1 = $(FILE_TEST:%=$(PATH1)%)
OBJECT1 = $(addprefix lnk/,$(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(FILE1))))
###################################################################
#second bunch
###################################################################
FORTRAN2 = ifort -traceback -c
PATH2 = sub/
FILE2 = second.f90
SOURCE2 = $(FILE2:%=$(PATH2)%)
OBJECT2 = $(addprefix lnk/,$(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(FILE2))))
###################################################################
# first rule
###################################################################
all: $(OBJECT1)
$(OBJECT1): lnk/%.o: $(PATH1)%.f90
   $(FORTRAN1) -o $@ $<
###################################################################
# second rule
###################################################################
all: $(OBJECT2)
$(OBJECT2): lnk/%.o: $(PATH2)%.f90
   $(FORTRAN2) -o $@ $<
```

Comment: There are two ways to tell `make` what to build: (i) by naming the wanted targets on the `make` command line; or (ii) if no targets are named on the command line, then the first explicit target in the makefile whose name does not begin with a `.`.  In addition to those targets, `make` will also build any of their prerequisites that it determines are out of date, recursively.  You are seeing (ii).  It is conventional, but not mandatory, to include a synthetic "`all`" target as the first one one the file, whose prerequisites are all the targets that should be built in a default run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make is not a scripting language: it's not the case that make reads the makefile and "executes" it while it is processed.  Make reads the entire makefile completely, plus all included files, then after it's done it starts processing.

There can only be one pattern rule with the same set of targets and prerequisites.  In your makefile you have:

```
PATH1 = sub/

PATH2 = sub/

lnk/%.o: $(PATH1)%.f90
   ...

lnk/%.o: $(PATH2)%.f90
   ...
```

Since `PATH1` and `PATH2` variables have the same value, make sees this:

```
lnk/%.o: sub/%.f90
   ...

lnk/%.o: sub/%.f90
   ...
```

the second rule is identical to the first rule, and so it overwrites it and the first rule is lost.  Then after all this parsing is complete, THEN make starts to try to build objects and see which rule should be used to match which target.  Since there's only one pattern rule that matches, it's used for all objects.

There are a few different ways you can do this.  One is by using [static pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html) instead of full pattern rules:

```
$(OBJECT1) : lnk/%.o: $(PATH1)%.f90
   ...

$(OBJECT2) : lnk/%.o: $(PATH2)%.f90
   ...
```

Now those rules match only those exact objects.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Maybe I made a mistake, but this solution executes only the first compilation command (see my edited question).

Comment: Why did you remove the `all:` targets?  You still need that.  Unless you specify some set of targets on the `make` command line, make will build only the first target that it finds in the makefile.  In your original makefile that was `all`, which depended on all the objects.  In your second makefile you removed the `all` target, which means the first target it found was the first object file in the `OBJECT1` variable, so that's all it will build by default.

Comment: I recommend you read the GNU Make manual, at the very least the intro section: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Introduction.html  It will save you asking a lot of questions on SO and elsewhere.